# How to change read_csv handling of empty values

Tags: python, pandas

When loading a header with missing values, pandas' read_csv creates a name like `Unnamed: 0_level_1`. How would I do to replace these with empty strings?

```
import pandas as pd

file = """A,B,C,C
,,C1,C2
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
"""

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(file)

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=[0, 1])
print(df.columns)
```

Comment: Your columns are A, B... or C1, C2?

Comment: The columns are a multiIndex. They are ('A', ''), ('B', ''), ('C', 'C1'), ('C', 'C2')

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in rename, something like:

```
data.rename( columns={0:'whatever you want'}, inplace=True )
```

More info https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

Answer (score 0):

In the process of CSV downloading You can put yours names of columns.

```
uruser_cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
users = pd.read_csv('C:/2/mlotek.csv', header=None, names=uruser_cols)
print(users.head())
```